# Convert all table columns into a binary string

Tags: sql

I currently have this sql

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW binary_input_table
AS
SELECT binary(CONCAT(column_1, column_2, column_3)) AS binary_input_str
FROM input_table;
```

where I need `binary_input_str` as an input to a custom UDF I made. However, this solution isn't scalable in case there are thousands of columns, which I would then have to CONCAT manually. I've also tried `SELECT binary(*)...` but fails as `binary` only expects one argument.

Is there an easy way to convert all the columns into binary and store it into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

`SELECT binary(CONCAT(*)) AS binary_input_str`